# NSThread gtm_performBlock Error

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk

I am trying to run the Street View example in the Google Maps SDK for iOS docs and am getting the following error:

> `-[NSThread gtm_performBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d55d1f0.
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSThread gtm_performBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d55d1f0'.
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception.

The strange thing is that I can get Street View to work in some projects and not others. I have tried both the Google 1.4.3 and 1.4.2 Frameworks and still get this error. Any idea what is causing it?

Answer (score 7):

Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the **Build Settings** tab:

-In the **Other Linker Flags** section, add *-ObjC*. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the **Build Settings** bar from **Basic** to **All**.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios

Comment: This is great, but where on that page do you see this mentioned?

Comment: Worked for me as well. I was able to get rid of `Unrecognised Selector` issue, but then got another one :(