# iOS, Error when initializing GMSPlacesClient - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to integrate Google Maps API's Autocomplete feature on the app.

I am trying to instantiate `GMSPlacesClient` on the a ViewController's viewDidLoad override, according to the documentation here.
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

```
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

`GMSServices` has been instantiated on the `AppDelegate` using my key.

But I'm getting the following error during instantiation.

```
2015-10-02 22:04:59.734 food2eat[93509:13849667] -[NSThread gtm_performBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc03f04f80
2015-10-02 22:04:59.766 food2eat[93509:13849667] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSThread gtm_performBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc03f04f80'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSThread gtm\_performBlock Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940147/nsthread-gtm-performblock-error)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. This error started after I changed the GMS API key.

Comment: For me it started when I started using CocoaPods

Answer (score 0):

Oh I figured it out alright! I remembered that It worked for me while not using CocoaPods.

I specifically remember that I needed to add a bunch of frameworks, but the important thing here is that you have to add the **-ObjC** flag, to the **Other Linker Flags** in your target's **Build Settings**.

After doing that it worked for me!